# QGIS attribute table - formatting views

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Is there a way to format the way attribute values are displayed in the attribute table?

For example, I would rather display the following columns to show comma-separated thousands and without the zeroes after the decimal point.

[image: unformatted view attribute table]

So, instead of "2300000.00000", it would display as "2,300,000" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot format the numbers directly, you need to create a field of type `String` first then use the following formula using Field Calculator in QGIS:

```
format_number(Field_name,0)
```

The format number is located under String category that's why creating a field of type `String` is necessary.

For example if you have a field of type `Real` with a name X , then add a field of type `String` and the formula will be `format_number("X",0)`. The 0 is to remove any decimal places and add comma-separated thousands.

Comment: I'm knocking myself on the head for not remembering how powerful the Field Calculator is!  Thank you @ahmadhanb

Comment: It works great but it would be nice to have a 'format' option in Layer properties -> Fields.

Comment: @Victor I agree with you, I hope it can be added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from @ahmadhanb which as mentioned, there doesn't seem to be away (yet) to change the formatting display of the attribute table! Another method is to use the `Float to Text` tool from the **MMQGIS** plugin, this tool converts your float fields into string automatically and outputs the result as a new shapefile. You can download/enable the plugin from the menubar.

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
```

---

1. Example attribute table:

   [image: Example attribute table]
2. From the menubar:

   ```
   MMQGIS > Modify > Float to Text
   ```

   [image: Float to Text]
3. Set the relevant options (the output **must** be saved somewhere other than the temp folder)

   [image: Float to Text options]
4. Result:

   [image: Result]